# Visual C linker behaves differently on 32-bit and 64-bit

Tags: c, visual-c++, dll

Take a look at the following example code:

```
__declspec(dllexport) FreeLibrary(void)
{ 
}
```

I build it as a DLL with the following little script:

```
cl /EHsc /MT /c test.c /Fotest.o
link /dll /out:test.dll test.o
```

This works fine when compiling for the 32-bit architecture. When compiling for the 64-bit architecture, however, the DLL isn't built and I get the following error:

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll) : error LNK2005: FreeLibrary already defined in test.o
    Creating library test.lib and object test.exp
test.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Why is that? Why does it work on 32-bit but not on 64-bit? Shouldn't the `FreeLibrary` symbol be defined in the 32-bit `kernel32.dll` as well? But why doesn't the 32-bit linker complain then and builds the DLL just fine?

This is really confusing to me...

Comment: You should *not* provide a definition of FreeLibrary().  It is an operating system function, you link kernel32.lib to tell the linker about it.  It is also declared wrong, use `#include <windows.h>` instead.  Pretty unclear how that did not fail your 32-bit build.

Comment: Well, I know that I should not do it but the question here is why does it work fine on 32-bit? I can even `LoadLibrary()` the 32-bit DLL and call into my custom `FreeLibrary()` function just fine... so why does Windows permit such things on 32-bit and not on 64-bit? That's the question here...

Comment: Your declaration is wrong.  That worked by accident in a 32-bit compiler because of the different name decoration used in 32-bit object files.  A 64-bit compiler uses no decoration, now the identifier becomes ambiguous with the OS function and the linker correctly complains.  Why you want to call FreeLibrary and not actually free the library is *very* hard to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to correct error spotted by IInspectable and for clarity**

## 32-bit

The default calling convention is [`__cdecl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2.aspx), which causes the symbol name to be prepended with an underscore:  `_FreeLibrary`.

```
>dumpbin /symbols test.o | find "FreeLibrary"
008 00000000 SECT3  notype ()    External     | _FreeLibrary
```

The `FreeLibrary` in kernel32.dll is declared with `WINAPI`.  In 32-bit, `WINAPI` expands to `__stdcall`, so kernel32's function is named `_FreeLibrary@4`.

```
>dumpbin /exports kernel32.lib | find "FreeLibrary"
    _FreeLibrary@4
    _FreeLibraryAndExitThread@8
    _FreeLibraryWhenCallbackReturns@8
```

Since `_FreeLibrary` doesn't match `_FreeLibrary@4`, there's no conflict.

## 64-bit

The default calling convention is a [four-register fastcall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) scheme that does not decorate the name of a plain C function.  Thus test.o defines a symbol named `FreeLibrary`:

```
>dumpbin /symbols test.o | find "FreeLibrary"
008 00000000 SECT3  notype ()    External     | FreeLibrary
```

Also, the `WINAPI` macro expands to nothing, so kernel32.dll uses the same default calling convention as your plugin code.  Thus it gets the same, unadorned symbol:

```
>dumpbin /exports kernel32.lib | find "FreeLibrary"
    FreeLibrary
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread
    FreeLibraryWhenCallbackReturns
```

This gives you two `FreeLibrary` symbols and results in the linker error.

Comment: Thanks. But now I have a problem: I'm porting an application to x64 whose plugins require a symbol named `FreeLibrary`. Of course, I could rename this for the x64 architecture to something that doesn't conflict with OS APIs but I'd rather stay consistent with the other architectures (Linux, Mac OS, x86 Windows) where using `FreeLibrary` isn't a problem. So is there a way to force x64 DLLs to use function decoration so that I can export a symbol named `FreeLibrary` in my DLL or is this generally not possible?

Comment: That's a different question and probably best asked in a new post.  I don't know of a way to do what you're asking offhand nor how such a thing would work (how would the system know which `FreeLibrary` to call?).  Name collisions are part of the reason things like COM were invented.  C APIs often use prefixes to help reduce the chance of collisions.  C++ has namespaces.  But none of those seem readily available to your current situation.

Comment: Asked a new question now about this. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301843/forcing-name-mangling-in-x64-dll

Comment: *"`__stdcall` calling convention [...] has no prefix (or suffix)"* - That's incorrect. With [__stdcall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx), *"[a]n underscore (\_) is prefixed to the name. The name is followed by the at sign (@) followed by the number of bytes (in decimal) in the argument list."*

Comment: Now I see my mistake.  I'll fix my answer.

Comment: The exports from the DLLs are undecorated. You'll find the decorated names when looking at the import libraries (LIBs). Running `dumpbin /EXPORTS kernel32.lib | findstr "LoadLibrary"` for both the x86 and x64 versions will show the difference (decorated vs. undecorated exports).