# Forcing name mangling in x64 DLL

Tags: c, windows, dll, 64-bit, name-mangling

I am porting a 32-bit application to 64-bit. The application supports plugins which are DLLs. Unfortunately, one of the mandatory functions each plugin needs to have is called `FreeLibrary` which of course conflicts with the `kernel32` API of the same name. The reason why my plugin API uses the `FreeLibrary` name is that the application originated on a different platform where `FreeLibrary` doesn't clash with any OS APIs.

However, even on 32-bit Windows using `FreeLibrary` is not a problem because 32-bit DLLs use name mangling, i.e. the function is stored as `_FreeLibrary` and hence doesn't clash with the `kernel32` API.

On 64-bit, though, I have a problem now because 64-bit doesn't seem to use name mangling. On 64-bit the compiler creates a symbol named `FreeLibrary` and this of course clashes with the `kernel32` API of the same name and refuses to link, leading to the following error:

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll) : error LNK2005: FreeLibrary already defined in test.o
    Creating library test.lib and object test.exp
test.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Thus, I'm wondering whether there is any way to force x64 DLLs to use name mangling as on 32-bit so that my DLL can export a symbol named `FreeLibrary` without any clashes with `kernel32`?

Or is there any other solution to work around this problem?

The only solution I see is to rename `FreeLibrary` to something that doesn't clash with OS APIs for the x64 versions of my application but of course I'd like to avoid this because it reduces the consistency of my application's plugin API. If possible, I'd like to keep the `FreeLibrary` name across all platforms and architectures.

Any ideas? I guess if it was possible on 32-bit to use reserved names like `FreeLibrary` in a DLL then there should be a way to do it on 64-bit as well, shouldn't there? But I don't see how...

Comment: When you say the application uses DLL-based plugins, I assume the application loads the plugins dynamically at runtime (e.g., it calls `LoadLibrary` and then `GetProcAddress` to find entry points in the plugin).  Is this true?  Or is the application actually linking against the export libraries of the plugins?  Given that your current solution depends on name mangling, I suspect the latter.

Comment: No, it actually uses `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to obtain function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to convince the compiler to mangle the names of the functions.  That way lies madness.

To clarify, your only issue is the duplicate symbols when linking plugin DLLs.  The application itself shouldn't care what the functions are named, because it's going to call the plugin entry points through function pointers received via `GetProcAddress`.

Assuming, the plugins don't ever need to call Windows APIs implemented in kernel32.dll, you could try omitting kernel32.dll from the linker command.  (See the `/NODEFAULTLIB` option.)  If kernel32.dll isn't part of the link, there should be no collision.

But that won't work because `/MT` in the command line implies you depend on the C run-time library, which, in turn, depends on some kernel32.dll APIs.  (Also, are you sure you want to link the plugins against the static run-time library and not the DLL version?)

So the remaining option is to change the name of the function.  This should be trivial, since you're porting anyway.  You could even use the preprocessor to hack the name when compiling the plugins so that you don't need to change their source code:

```
cl /EHsc /c /DFreeLibrary=Plugin_FreeLibrary /Fotest.o test.c
```

And then change the `GetProcAddress` call in the application to look for `Plugin_FreeLibrary` instead of `FreeLibrary`, which I assume happens in just one place.

Comment: Yes, the name change approach of course came to my mind as well, but that's what I wanted to avoid for consistency reasons (see original post). But if there is really no other way, I'll go with it of course...

Comment: The names never were exactly what you thought they were because of the name mangling, so it would seem that a name change would be a minor thing.  You can still have consistency.  Nothing about my suggestion requires treating any platform differently than any other.

Comment: But IIUC your suggestion requires me to use different names on x86 and x64, e.g. `FreeLibrary` on x86 but `_FreeLibrary` (or something similar) on x64. It doesn't matter that the compiler didn't really use `FreeLibrary` on x86 either. What matters is what is in the source codes and in the source codes I could just use `FreeLibrary` and `GetProcAddress("FreeLibrary")` on x86, even though the symbol wasn't really called `FreeLibrary`. On x64 this is impossible. I have to use a macro on x64 which changes the symbol name to something that doesn't clash both in the function declaration and in the

Comment: import call to `GetProcAddress`. In my eyes, this means treating x64 differently than x86. Sure, it's not a big deal and can be done quite elegantly using macros but still, for me this means treating x64 differently than x86 because on x86 I could just use `FreeLibrary` in the source codes (even though it never really was `FreeLibrary`) whereas on x64 this is impossible because there is no name mangling on x64.

Comment: By the way, what is strange is that when opening my x86 plugin DLL in PEInfo the exported symbol name is really listed as `FreeLibrary`, not as `_FreeLibrary`. Only when taking a look at a hex dump of my object files generated by the compiler can I see that the symbol name seems to be `_FreeLibrary` in reality. Still, I think it's strange that PEInfo (and also when hex dumping the DLL) says that the exported function is indeed named `FreeLibrary`. So there must be some magic going on that turns `FreeLibrary` into `_FreeLibrary` when loading the DLL because the symbol's name is `FreeLibrary`.